# How to make two tikzpicture's appear one same row

Tags: tikz-pgf, subfloats

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document} 

\begin{figure}

\centering

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[step=0.5cm,color=gray] (0,0) grid (1.5,3.5);

% Row Headers
\node at (-0.25,+3.25) {$r_0$};
\node at (-0.25,+2.75) {$r_1$};
\node at (-0.25,+2.25) {$r_2$};
\node at (-0.25,+1.75) {$r_3$};
\node at (-0.25,+1.25) {$r_4$};
\node at (-0.25,+0.75) {$r_5$};
\node at (-0.25,+0.25) {$r_6$};

% Column 1
\node at (+0.25,+3.75) {$c_1$};
\node at (+0.25,+3.25) {0};
\node at (+0.25,+2.75) {1};
\node at (+0.25,+2.25) {2};
\node at (+0.25,+1.75) {3};
\node at (+0.25,+1.25) {4};
\node at (+0.25,+0.75) {5};
\node at (+0.25,+0.25) {6};

% Column 2
\node at (+0.75,+3.75) {$c_2$};
\node at (+0.75,+3.25) {7};
\node at (+0.75,+2.75) {8};
\node at (+0.75,+2.25) {9};
\node at (+0.75,+1.75) {10};
\node at (+0.75,+1.25) {11};
\node at (+0.75,+0.75) {12};
\node at (+0.75,+0.25) {13};

% Column 3
\node at (+1.25,+3.75) {$c_3$};
\node at (+1.25,+3.25) {14};
\node at (+1.25,+2.75) {15};
\node at (+1.25,+2.25) {16};
\node at (+1.25,+1.75) {17};
\node at (+1.25,+1.25) {18};
\node at (+1.25,+0.75) {19};
\node at (+1.25,+0.25) {20};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}

% -- No Swap
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=0.5cm,color=gray] (0,0) grid (1.5,3.5);

% Row Headers
\node at (-0.25,+3.25) {$r_0$};
\node at (-0.25,+2.75) {$r_1$};
\node at (-0.25,+2.25) {$r_2$};
\node at (-0.25,+1.75) {$r_3$};
\node at (-0.25,+1.25) {$r_4$};
\node at (-0.25,+0.75) {$r_5$};
\node at (-0.25,+0.25) {$r_6$};

% Column 1
\node at (+0.25,+3.75) {$c_1$};
\node at (+0.25,+3.25) {0};
\node at (+0.25,+2.75) {3};
\node at (+0.25,+2.25) {6};
\node at (+0.25,+1.75) {9};
\node at (+0.25,+1.25) {12};
\node at (+0.25,+0.75) {15};
\node at (+0.25,+0.25) {18};

% Column 2
\node at (+0.75,+3.75) {$c_2$};
\node at (+0.75,+3.25) {1};
\node at (+0.75,+2.75) {4};
\node at (+0.75,+2.25) {7};
\node at (+0.75,+1.75) {10};
\node at (+0.75,+1.25) {13};
\node at (+0.75,+0.75) {16};
\node at (+0.75,+0.25) {19};

% Column 3
\node at (+1.25,+3.75) {$c_3$};
\node at (+1.25,+3.25) {2};
\node at (+1.25,+2.75) {5};
\node at (+1.25,+2.25) {8};
\node at (+1.25,+1.75) {11};
\node at (+1.25,+1.25) {14};
\node at (+1.25,+0.75) {17};
\node at (+1.25,+0.25) {20};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I want these two grids side by side, not above one another. How is that done?

[image]

Comment: Have a look at pgfmanual.pdf, 'baseline'

Comment: Welcome! Please provide complete examples rather than code snippets. Depending on the rest of your code, one of the pictures might appear on a different page, there might be no room for it on the same line or it might be replaced by a box. We can't reproduce what you're seeing. In this case, we can guess and the guess is likely correct, but it's still a guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blank lines are interpreted as paragraph breaks, so removing the blank line between the subfigures puts them on the same row.

[image: Two tables created with TikZ, side by side. Each table has seven rows and three columns of integers, and each row and column is indexed starting at zero. The table on the left has the caption (a) my first TikZ table. The table on the on the right has the caption (b) my second TikZ table.]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document} 

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[step=0.5cm,color=gray] (0,0) grid (1.5,3.5);

% Row Headers
\node at (-0.25,+3.25) {$r_0$};
\node at (-0.25,+2.75) {$r_1$};
\node at (-0.25,+2.25) {$r_2$};
\node at (-0.25,+1.75) {$r_3$};
\node at (-0.25,+1.25) {$r_4$};
\node at (-0.25,+0.75) {$r_5$};
\node at (-0.25,+0.25) {$r_6$};

% Column 1
\node at (+0.25,+3.75) {$c_1$};
\node at (+0.25,+3.25) {0};
\node at (+0.25,+2.75) {1};
\node at (+0.25,+2.25) {2};
\node at (+0.25,+1.75) {3};
\node at (+0.25,+1.25) {4};
\node at (+0.25,+0.75) {5};
\node at (+0.25,+0.25) {6};

% Column 2
\node at (+0.75,+3.75) {$c_2$};
\node at (+0.75,+3.25) {7};
\node at (+0.75,+2.75) {8};
\node at (+0.75,+2.25) {9};
\node at (+0.75,+1.75) {10};
\node at (+0.75,+1.25) {11};
\node at (+0.75,+0.75) {12};
\node at (+0.75,+0.25) {13};

% Column 3
\node at (+1.25,+3.75) {$c_3$};
\node at (+1.25,+3.25) {14};
\node at (+1.25,+2.75) {15};
\node at (+1.25,+2.25) {16};
\node at (+1.25,+1.75) {17};
\node at (+1.25,+1.25) {18};
\node at (+1.25,+0.75) {19};
\node at (+1.25,+0.25) {20};

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{My first Ti$k$Z table}
\end{subfigure}
%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=0.5cm,color=gray] (0,0) grid (1.5,3.5);

% Row Headers
\node at (-0.25,+3.25) {$r_0$};
\node at (-0.25,+2.75) {$r_1$};
\node at (-0.25,+2.25) {$r_2$};
\node at (-0.25,+1.75) {$r_3$};
\node at (-0.25,+1.25) {$r_4$};
\node at (-0.25,+0.75) {$r_5$};
\node at (-0.25,+0.25) {$r_6$};

% Column 1
\node at (+0.25,+3.75) {$c_1$};
\node at (+0.25,+3.25) {0};
\node at (+0.25,+2.75) {3};
\node at (+0.25,+2.25) {6};
\node at (+0.25,+1.75) {9};
\node at (+0.25,+1.25) {12};
\node at (+0.25,+0.75) {15};
\node at (+0.25,+0.25) {18};

% Column 2
\node at (+0.75,+3.75) {$c_2$};
\node at (+0.75,+3.25) {1};
\node at (+0.75,+2.75) {4};
\node at (+0.75,+2.25) {7};
\node at (+0.75,+1.75) {10};
\node at (+0.75,+1.25) {13};
\node at (+0.75,+0.75) {16};
\node at (+0.75,+0.25) {19};

% Column 3
\node at (+1.25,+3.75) {$c_3$};
\node at (+1.25,+3.25) {2};
\node at (+1.25,+2.75) {5};
\node at (+1.25,+2.25) {8};
\node at (+1.25,+1.75) {11};
\node at (+1.25,+1.25) {14};
\node at (+1.25,+0.75) {17};
\node at (+1.25,+0.25) {20};

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{My second Ti$k$Z table}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, that simple "%" after the "\end{subfigure}" did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Why are you using TikZ for this?
A simple `tabular` is enough.
Here I use `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\NewTblrEnviron{mytab}
\SetTblrInner[mytab]{
    columns={.5cm, colsep=0pt, mode=math},
    rows={.5cm, rowsep=0pt},
    cells={c,m},
    stretch=0,
    hline{2-Z} = {2-Z}{gray},
    vline{2-Z} = {2-Z}{gray},
    }

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document} 

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{mytab}{}
    & c_1 & c_2 & c_3 \\
r_0 & 0   & 7   & 14  \\
r_1 & 1   & 8   & 15  \\
r_2 & 2   & 9   & 16  \\
r_3 & 3   & 10  & 17  \\
r_4 & 4   & 11  & 18  \\
r_5 & 5   & 12  & 19  \\
r_6 & 6   & 13  & 20  \\
\end{mytab}
\caption{My first Ti\emph{k}Z table}
\end{subfigure}
%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{mytab}{}
    & c_1 & c_2 & c_3 \\
r_0 & 0   & 1   & 2   \\
r_1 & 3   & 4   & 5   \\
r_2 & 6   & 7   & 8   \\
r_3 & 9   & 10  & 11  \\
r_4 & 12  & 13  & 14  \\
r_5 & 15  & 16  & 17  \\
r_6 & 18  & 19  & 20  \\
\end{mytab}
\caption{My second Ti\emph{k}Z table}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Off-topic: don't use `$...$` to italicize words, it is reserved to math-mode. Use `\emph{...}` instead.

Answer (score 3):

LaTeX converts new lines to spaces and empty lines to actually new lines in output documents, or so-to-say new paragraphs. In your case, remove the empty line and you will get images next to each other.

A few remarks. If you want to stick with `tikz`, consider using `matrix` library and styles to avoid excessive code and repetitions. Also, note that `subcaption` package loads `caption` and there is no need to load it explicitly.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\tikzset{
  grid/.style = {
    draw,
    color = gray!50,
    text = black,
    inner sep=0pt,
    outer sep=0pt,
    minimum size = 7mm,
    anchor = center,
  },
  mstyle/.style = {
    matrix of math nodes,
    column sep = -\pgflinewidth,
    row sep = -\pgflinewidth,
    nodes = {grid},
    column 1/.style = {nodes={draw=none}},
    row 1/.style = {nodes={draw=none}},
  },
}

\subcaptionsetup{format=hang}


\begin{document} 
\begin{figure}
  \AddToHook{env/tikzpicture/before}{\centering}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \matrix[mstyle] {
        & c_1 & c_2 & c_3 \\
        r_0 & 0   & 7   & 14 \\
        r_1 & 1   & 8   & 15 \\
        r_2 & 2   & 9   & 16 \\
        r_3 & 3   & 10  & 17 \\
        r_4 & 4   & 11  & 18 \\
        r_5 & 5   & 12  & 19 \\
        r_6 & 6   & 13  & 20 \\
      };
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Caption for the first image}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \hfil
  \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \matrix[mstyle] {
        & c_1 & c_2 & c_3 \\
        r_0 & 0   & 1   & 2 \\
        r_1 & 3   & 4   & 5 \\
        r_2 & 6   & 7   & 8 \\
        r_3 & 9   & 10  & 11 \\
        r_4 & 12  & 13  & 14 \\
        r_5 & 15  & 16  & 17 \\
        r_6 & 18  & 18  & 20 \\
      };
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Caption for the second image}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]